# How to persist data to any controller action in a project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, data-persistence

I would like to have an auto-save for the forms on some of my website's pages. So I hook into `window.onbeforeunload` to submit forms. My issue is that I'd like to give them a success or error message with `toastr` but I don't know if something already exists to persist the data from one controller action to **any** action on the site. I don't think I will be able to use redirects with tempdata or the viewbag. Does this functionality exist already?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to look into Action Filters, you can capture the Action Result in the Action Filter and Save the data. Also you can apply action filters selectively to Actions or Globally. Have a look here - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use models? I think the best way to pass data through controllers is just passing the model you submit to respective actions like

```
return View("ViewName",model);
```

Or use `RedirectToAction` if you have to acess another controller

```
return RedirectToAction("YourAction", "YourController", new {model = yourModel});
```

To toastr I recommend create a wrapper, see http://labs.bjfocus.co.uk/2014/06/create-an-mvc-wrapper-for-toastr/

Comment: I am allowing the user to go to any page so I can't use the redirect without adding some way of posting the redirect location with the rest of the data.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get this to work by using `OnActionExecuting` similar to [Preet Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244007/preet-singh)'s response but with some additional pieces.

```
    public const string SESSION_ERROR = "SessionError";
    public const string SESSION_SUCCESS = "SessionSuccess";

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        ViewBag.Error = HttpContext.Session[SESSION_ERROR];
        ViewBag.Success = HttpContext.Session[SESSION_SUCCESS];
        HttpContext.Session[SESSION_ERROR] = string.Empty;
        HttpContext.Session[SESSION_SUCCESS] = string.Empty;
    }
```

The code above is used to persist the messages to any controller action and allows me to set the messages easily with the `HttpContext.Session`. This code is in a `BaseController` and all controllers extend it.